# Как вывести ссылку для активации таба (вкладки) woocoommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

В woocommerce в карточке товара есть вкладки: описание, характеристики и т.д.

В тексте "описания", хочу сделать ссылку, кликнув по которой, происходила активация вкладки "характеристики". Как будто я кликнул мышкой по самой вкладке #tab-specification.

Весь инет перерыл, не могу найти решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил в onclick:

```
$('#tab-title-specification a').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

самое простое решение в этом случае с использованием js. вы размещаете в описании якорную ссылку `<a href="#tab-specification">характеристики</a>` и потом отлавливаете клик по ссылкам такого типа в описании. если тема платная то селекторы могут отличатся

```
jQuery( '.woocommerce-Tabs-panel [href="#tab-specification"]' ).click( function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery( '.wc-tabs [href="#tab-specification"]' ).click();
} );
```